# Call class variable insida a mixin - Sass

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, frontend

I have 2 classes that styles a header. Then I need to create a mixin to custom a background modal, depending on which header is being showed.

Is it possible to use the $has-dept variable inside my mixin?

```
    //header 1
     .dt-style-user-bar-without-departments {
          @extend .dt-style-user-bar;
          $has-dept: false;
          /...
    }

    //header 2
    .dt-style-user-bar-with-departments {
          @extend .dt-style-user-bar;
          $has-dept: false;
          //...
    }

    //intending to get $has-dept var to give the proper background color   
    @mixin set-reveal-bg-color(){
          @extend $has-dept;
          @if $has-dept {
            background: green !important;
          }
          @else {
            background: blue !important;
          }
    }

   //prints the background color in the modal overlay class
    .reveal-modal-bg{
      @include set-reveal-bg-color()
    }
```

*output: error scss/app.scss (Line 471 of scss/_dt_style.scss: Undefined variable: "$has-dept".)*

Comment: You can't use `@extend` directive for variables, it is only available for selectors. From [SASS reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend): The `@extend` directive avoids these problems by telling Sass that one **selector** should inherit the styles of another **selector** [...]

Comment: Can you show what you want to achieve in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just enable variable interpolation like this:

```
@extend #{$has-dept};
```

This makes Sass evaluate the value of the variable right there.

Here's more on Sass interpolation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_